# Convert a list of file type, in a regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

**I don't ask how validate upload file**

I need to set a PHP regex like this:

```
'/\.(pdf|doc|docx)$/i'
```

from a list like this:

```
 .pdf,.doc,.docx
```

The goal is set the accept file types, in an upload form.

I tried:

```
$filetype_arr = explode("," , ".pdf,.doc,.docx");
$filetype_str = '/\.(';
for ($i=0; $i < count($filetype_arr) ; $i++) { 
    $filetype_ext = explode("." , $filetype_arr[$i]);
    $pipe = "";
    if ($i < count($filetype_arr) - 1) $pipe = "|";
    $filetype_str .= $filetype_ext[1] . $pipe;
}
$filetype_str .= ')$/i';
// $filetype_str = '/\.(pdf|doc|docx)$/i'

'accept_file_types' => $filetype_str,
```

And don't works, but:

```
'accept_file_types' => '/\.(pdf|doc|docx)$/i',
```

Works.

**EDIT:**
As title says: "I need to convert a list in a RegEx in php" ... I don't ask how validate upload file, it's not duplicate.
This regex will be insert in a library for upload file, and I just need to set the valid extension from a dynamic list.

```
'accept_file_types' => '/\.(' . $myDynamicList . ')$/i',
```

**Simplify:**

Dont works:

```
$validFile = '/\.(' . str_replace(',.', '|', ".pdf,.doc,.docx") . ')$/i';
'accept_file_types' => $validFile,
```

It works:

```
'accept_file_types' => '/\.(pdf|doc|docx)$/i',
```

Many thanks

Comment: You have a string like `"pdf,.doc,.docx"`, and you want to construct a regular expression from this string, right?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk please read the edit, thanks.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov yes!

Answer (score 0):

```
$spec = '.pdf,.doc,.docx';
$regex = substr($spec, 1);
$regex = str_replace(',.', '|', $regex);
$regex = '/\.(' . $regex . ')$/';

echo preg_match($regex, 'filename.pdf') ? 'matched' : 'not matched';
echo "\n";
echo preg_match($regex, 'filename.xyz') ? 'matched' : 'not matched';
echo "\n";
```